# Delimiters and Translation TexStudio Macros

Tags: macros, texstudio

I haven't been able to figure out in TexStudio how to set a macro so that every time I type:" $ " I will get: " $$ " with the cursor in the middle, any ideas? Also, how could I set a translation macro, so that when I type: " [ " I get: " {} " with the cursor in the middle and vice versa, i.e. " { " --> " [] " ?

Thank you for your time and insights!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your questions are quite specific for a particular TeX-Tool. Some users here might use TeXStudio, but if you get no answer in reasonable time, try the [discussion forum for TeXStudio](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a macro with corresponding trigger. Triggers are regular expressions, so you have to escape `$` and `[` if you want to use them literally.

For example, here is the code for your `$` question.

[image]

The others work likewise.